# Control of header file for objective-c library

Tags: objective-c, import, static-libraries, header-files

I am writing a obj-c fake library for iphone. I need to deploy the library to my client for project perpose, but I don't want any vialation of my property. I want to give a single header file along with the library which can be used by my client. But problem is something like: My Class A extends class B, class B extends class C. I want to give the header of class A (file A.h) to client, But there's code like "import B.h" in "A.h", so if I do not expose my B.h, It won't compile in my client's project, And so as class C and furthor deep base classes.
And I can't expose these classes cause these would expose all of my structures and leads vialations of my property.
Please help and thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, Caleb, Thanks for helping. But it seems that @class keyword can't be used for a base class, this gonna report a compile error in xcode.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments to Caleb's answer, a class has to be able to see the `@interface` of its superclass.

But here is what you can do.  The interface for `ClassB` can be pretty much empty, except for the designated initialiser.  You can then put all of your internal-to-your-library properties and methods in a category in a separate header file. e.g.

```
// ClassA.h ---------------------
#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassA : ClassB

// stuff

@end

// ClassB.h --------------------- 

@interface ClassB : NSObject

// Properties and methods on ClassB that really are public (possibly none).

@end

// ClassB+Internal.h ---------------------

#import "ClassB.h"

@interface ClassB(Internal) // "Internal" can be anything you like

@property (copy) NSString* mySecretProperty;

// etc

@end

// ClassB.m ---------------------

@interface ClassB()  // Class extension
// Really secret properties and methods not to be seen outside of this file.
@property (copy) NSString* myReallySecretProperty;

@end

@implementation ClassB

@synthesize mySecretProperty;

@end
```

Normally you would create an implementation for the Internal category, but *you don't actually need to* as long as the methods exist at runtime.

Comment: Thank you  JeremyP, This is a good idea. I am working on it to change my structure into this design pattern.